AssertionError when assigning set with a single element in numba njit method
I'm trying to use numba's njit decorator to optimize a method. I'm getting an error that seems to be caused by defining a set with multiple elements, then overwriting it with a set with a single element (or vice versa).
I'm running python 3.10.12, numba version 0.60.0.
The following minimal example reproduces the error
import numba


@numba.njit
def foo(n: int):
    s = {1, 2, 3}
    if n == 1:
        pass
    else:
        s = {2}  # This causes an error
        # s = {2, 3, 4}  # This works

    res = sum(list(s))
    return res


def main():
    res = foo(2)
    print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

According to the numba docs

All methods and operations on sets are supported in JIT-compiled functions.

so I don't understand what causes an error in this case. Even doing sum(s) without converting to a list beforehand throws an error.
What is the cause of the error, and how can I make it work?

I got an error with def foo(n): return {1} if n else {2} as well. Not exactly the same stack trace, but I think it's the same cause. Even if we did something wrong, numba should give a more user-friendly error, not AssertionError with no info.

I guess the redefinition of the set within if/else statement is the problem here. Modifying the contents s.clear();s.add(2) works without any error.

I’ve analyzed the issue and here’s what I found.
The problem seems to stem from the way sets are interpreted depending on the number of elements they contain.
Specifically, when a set has just one element, it’s treated as a literal type, while with two or more elements, it’s interpreted as a non-literal type.
You can verify how the types are being interpreted by following:
from numba import njit


@njit
def func():
    a = {1}
    b = {1, 2}
    return a, b


func()
func.inspect_types()

Here’s the key point:
#   a = build_set(items=[Var($const4.0, temp.py:6)])  :: set(Literal[int](1))
#   b = build_set(items=[Var($const10.2, temp.py:7), Var($const12.3, temp.py:7)])  :: set(int64)

The type of each variable is indicated after the :: symbol.
As you can see, a is a set of Literal[int], while b is a set of int64.
Just as it is not possible to assign a float64 value to an int64 variable, the two are not compatible.
Now that we know the cause, the workaround is simple: prevent a set of one element from being interpreted as a literal type.
For example, you can do something like this:
@njit
def func():
    a = set((1,))
    b = {1, 2}
    return a, b

This will ensure that both a and b are interpreted as set(int64).
#   a = call $4load_global.0($const14.2, func=$4load_global.0, args=[Var($const14.2, temp.py:6)], kws=(), vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None)  :: (UniTuple(int64, 1),) -> set(int64)
#   b = build_set(items=[Var($const26.4, temp.py:7), Var($const28.5, temp.py:7)])  :: set(int64)

I made the same change to your code and it now works as expected.
import numba


@numba.njit
def foo(n: int):
    s = {1, 2, 3}
    if n == 1:
        pass
    else:
        s = set((2,))

    res = sum(list(s))
    return res


def main():
    res = foo(1)
    print(res)
    res = foo(2)
    print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Alternatively, you could implement it like this if you like.
@numba.njit
def non_literal_set(*args):
    return set(args)


@numba.njit
def foo(n: int):
    s = non_literal_set(1, 2, 3)
    if n == 1:
        pass
    else:
        s = non_literal_set(2)

    res = sum(list(s))
    return res

